# Rotate image 90 degrees using GD

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to generate some text and rotate the entire image by 90 degrees, not the individual letters. It has to be a transparent PNG and use no existing image as a base.

Thanks

Comment: Nice, and what you want from us? ._.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php?

Comment: and what have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this script a try

```
define("DEFAULT_FONT", "fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf");
define("DEFAULT_COLOR", "ed217c");
define("DEFAULT_SIZE", 24);
define("DEFAULT_ANGLE", 0);
define("DEFAULT_PADDING", 10);
define("DEFAULT_SPACING", 0);

$text = $_GET['text'];
if(isset($_GET['transform'])):
    switch ($_GET['transform']){
        case 'uc':
            $text = strtoupper($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'lc':
            $text = strtolower($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'ucf':
            $text = ucfirst($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'ucw':
            $text = ucwords($_GET['text']);
            break;
    }
endif;

$font = $_GET['font'] ? $_GET['font'] : DEFAULT_FONT;
$color = (strlen($_GET['color']) == 6 && ctype_alnum($_GET['color']))  ? "0x" . $_GET['color'] : "0x" . DEFAULT_COLOR;
$size = (is_numeric($_GET['size'])) ? $_GET['size'] : DEFAULT_SIZE;
$angle = (is_numeric($_GET['angle'])) ? $_GET['angle'] : DEFAULT_ANGLE;
$padding = (is_numeric($_GET['padding'])) ? $_GET['padding']*4 : DEFAULT_PADDING*4;
$spacing = (is_numeric($_GET['spacing'])) ? $_GET['spacing'] : DEFAULT_SPACING;
$text_dimensions = calculateTextDimensions($text, $font, $size, $angle, $spacing);
$image_width = $text_dimensions["width"] + $padding;
$image_height = $text_dimensions["height"] + $padding;

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);
ImageFill($new_image, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagettftextSp($new_image, $size, $angle, $text_dimensions["left"] + ($image_width / 2) - ($text_dimensions["width"] / 2), $text_dimensions["top"] + ($image_height / 2) - ($text_dimensions["height"] / 2), $color, $font, $text, $spacing);
imagepng($new_image);
imagerotate($new_image, 90, 0);
imagedestroy($new_image);

function imagettftextSp($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0)
{
    if ($spacing == 0)
    {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $temp_x = $x;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
        {
            $bbox = imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $temp_x, $y, $color, $font, $text[$i]);
            $temp_x += $spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]);
        }
    }
}

function calculateTextDimensions($text, $font, $size, $angle, $spacing) {
    $rect = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);
    $minX = min(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
    $maxX = max(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
    $minY = min(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));
    $maxY = max(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));
    $spacing = ($spacing*(strlen($text)+2));
    return array(
        "left"   => abs($minX) - 1,
        "top"    => abs($minY) - 1,
        "width"  => ($maxX - $minX)+$spacing,
        "height" => $maxY - $minY,
        "box"    => $rect
    );
}
    header("content-type: image/png");
```

You can pass the rotation angle in to the script via the IMG SRC tag. I'm using this in a Wordpress install, but my code to generate looks like this...

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imgCreate.php?text=<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>&font=&transform=&size=45&angle=90&color=&padding=18&spacing=0" />
```

Comment: Covers all the requirements and then some. Anything that isn't used will default to the defines at the top. 

Only thing to note is the rotation doesn't take in a negative value, so -90 would be 270. OP didn't specify 90deg clockwise or counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagerotate()` from gd library:

```
$img = imagerotate($img, 90, 0);
```

1st parameter is image source i.e. from `imagecreatefrompng()`
2nd parameter is degrees
3rd parameter is background color

See more on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score -4):

This is the best method for rotating an image using GD lib.

```
$img = new Imagick('image.png'); 
$img->rotateImage( new ImagickPixel('none'), 7 ); 
$img->trimImage ( 0 );  
$img->writeImage('rotateImage.png');  
$img->destroy();
```

Comment: _using gd_. This is CSS.

Comment: @putvande-i Believe this is the answer.

Comment: PNG with transparency, not JPG

Comment: That is imagemagick, not gd...